# Python module in tensorflow anaconda installation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working in anaconda environment
I used conda install tensorflow to install tensorflow
In the code I :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset
```

The first command passes but the second command does not (Import error)
I looked In the github of tensorflow and saw that the tensorflow.python.data   module exists but probably changed
Is there a way to get Dataset class from the anaconda installation?
If not is there a workaround ?
Ilan

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that i used :

```
conda install tensorflow
```

rather than follow the instructions in the tensorflow site
Ilan